# image doesn't fully fit its container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put an image in a container but for some reason, there is always a small additional space at the end of the image: Here is a fiddle with tests: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sikAm. If you look at the last one in the right bar, there is no white because the container hides the overflow. This made me think that the problem happens because of the image, not because of the container. So the container's size gets that white because the image "pushes" an additional space inside. However, the image's size is correct and it has no margin that can add this at the bottom, so I might be completely on the wrong track:

```
img {
  border: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I don't know what to do about this. What can cause that whitespace? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, images are inline elements, and its [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property defaults to `baseline`. This alignment produces some space below the element.

To fix it, you can use

- `display: block` [[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cLDqd)]. This way the element will no longer be inline-level, so `vertical-align` won't apply.
- `vertical-align: middle` [[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uqyHk)]. This fixes the alignment problem. Other values may also work.

Comment: whitespaces are not caused because of newlines and spaces of HTML codes.

Comment: @aniskhan001 Yes, sorry. I was confused because newlines and spaces may cause problematic spaces too, but not in this case. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`img`s are displayed `inline` by default, which creates spaces automatically for next line of texts.

Instead set the `display` to `block`. It will make those spaces gone.

```
img {
    display:block
}
```